How to verify Mifare Transaction MAC?
Our project is using Mifare Desfire cards with Transaction MAC enabled.
We read https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/data-sheet/MF2DLHX0.pdf and other NXP's documents too.
We finished coding on the client side by sending APDU command and receiving response. The card also generate TMV  (Transaction MAC Value)
We want to verify TMV on the server side.
My questions are:

Is there any available library (Java or NodeJs) to verify TMV generated by the Desfire cards?
Is there any HSM supporting the Transaction MAC?

Thanks,
